# How to dynamically change which client handles an event in a single X window (Java)?

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, x11

## Introduction

In my Java code, I create an AWT `Canvas` object. This `Canvas` is inside of a `JFrame`. Using the [JNIWrapper library](https://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper) (more specifically, the JAWT subcomponent), I acquire the window ID on this window. In a separate program (which I'll call *Program B*), I draw to this window.

Recently, event handling was added to *Program B*. If *Program B* is run and given the handle to my `Canvas` AWT component, and then draws on that window ID, mouse press events are sent to *Program B*, and ignored in the Java program.

## Question

How can I implement a strategy for the Java program to programmatically change whether mouse press events are received by the Java program or sent off to *Program B*?

Comment: Do you know that you can draw on a `JPanel`? Then you don't need to mix AWT components, like `Canvas`, with _Swing_ components. Also, I presume that _Program B_ is **not** java code. Am I correct in that presumption?

Comment: @Abra The JNIWrapper library requires that in order to draw on the window in this way that the component in question be either an AWT canvas or a window [(JNIWrapper docs)](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jniwrapper/javadoc/com/jniwrapper/jawt/JAWT.html#getDrawingSurface(java.awt.Component)). This is the only reason why an AWT component is used. And yes, _Program B_ is not Java code.

Comment: Can't you add a mouse listener to the `Canvas` in your java code?

Comment: @Abra A mouse listener was added to the `Canvas`, and it registers mouse presses up until the point where _Program B_ begins drawing to the screen. According to [the Wikipedia article on X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol), "there are some kinds of events that can only be selected by one client at time for each window. In particular, these events report mouse button clicks and some changes related to window management." I think that might be what's going on here.

Comment: Is _Program B_ simulating mouse events on the `Canvas`?

Comment: @Abra _Program B_ is requesting mouse events from the window and doing different things with them than the Java program will do.  Ultimately, the goal is to have most mouse clicks are sent to _Program B_,  and when shift is pressed those mouse click events are sent to the Java program.